# CSS for printing purposes from mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-website

I'm building an app for Android that will print a web page to a Bluetooth printer
the problem is that the dimensions of my divs and font sizes are changing from screen resolution to another, from a 10.1 tab to 4.7 inch phone and 3.5

I tried to use almost all the units: pt, em, px...

one solution now is to make a resolution specific sheets, but is it the only way!!!

Comment: Bluetooth printers do not necessarily have screen resolutions, since Bluetooth printers do not necessarily have screens. Hence, it is unclear why you care about screen resolution for printed output. That being said, in CSS, `px` represents a density-independent pixel, roughly analogous to the `dp` used in Android (though CSS' `px` takes zoom into account).

Comment: I print a web page, the resolution of the mobile device affecting the page displayed on it, I'm using another app intent to print using it

Comment: Then perhaps you should contact the developer of the other app to inquire about why screen resolution is affecting printed results and how you should address that in your app. That other developer is unlikely to see your question here, and nobody else is likely going to be able to assist you with your issues with that unnamed program.

Comment: it's "printer share" for android
just assume I'm just building a web site for mobile, is it supposed to be affected by the resolution ?!

Comment: Are you printing more like a screenshot of your page or just the content of your page?

Comment: the content of the page, a web page